# How to get information about the class in dart?

Tags: class, dart

I'm coming from java to dart and there are a lot of similarity between the two but one thing am trying to do is to get some info about a class in dart like the instance variables , methods and constructors but I couldn't know how , i mean like in java class `Class` , class  `Package`  and class `Method` are simple presentation of them self but in dart i couldn't find any but class `Type` witch it's a blank class and running `type.runTime` returns `_Type` so am stuck here , tried to google it but all i found is the oop basics of dart , in short , How to get the equivalent of those java classes in Dart ? and thanks in advance .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `dart:mirrors` package for those. [ClassMirror class](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.4.0/dart-mirrors/ClassMirror-class.html) maybe help you on this.

```
  TestClass test = new TestClass();
  var im = reflect(test);
  print(im.type.declarations.values);
  print(im.type.location);
  print(im.type.qualifiedName);
  print(test.runtimeType.toString());
```

Will give you the data you are looking for i think.

If you try without initialization `var im = reflect(TestClass);` instead of already init object. It is just dart.core._Type and you will get only

```
(MethodMirror on 'hashCode', MethodMirror on '_Type')
dart:core-patch/type_patch.dart:15
Symbol("dart.core._Type")
```

Comment: it seems like i was looking in the wrong way ,,,, thank you .