# how to check if getter is defined or not for a class in dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

Is there any way to check if a getter is provided for a dynamic variable in dart
other then in try catch block?

example
here 'v1' is not provided in 'ThisClass' so it will give an error

```
class ThisClass{
  bool v2=false;
}

main() {
  dynamic h=ThisClass();
  
  print(h.v1);
}
```

Comment: https://www.woolha.com/tutorials/dart-getting-list-of-fields-and-methods-in-a-class

Comment: @Doc update your answer to include dart Mirrors as you have mentioned. Its probably the solution, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57401821/13625305) is one of the previous answers

Answer (score 4):

You could do

```
class ThisClass {
  bool v2 = false;
}

main() {
  dynamic h = ThisClass();
  if (h is ThisClass) {
    print(h.v2);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can attempt to access the variable in a `try` block and catch the resulting error if it doesn't exist:

```
try {
  print(h.v1);
} catch (e) {
  // Handle the error
}
```